# Dairy hechsher but no dairy ingredients listed

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, hechsher-certification, dairy

Suppose that a food product has a dairy hechsher (say, OU-D) but does not have anything obviously dairy in the ingredients list, and does not have "contains dairy" or something similar written below the ingredients list. May one eat this product immediately after eating fleishigs?